# How to stop console output for log4j ? Current code will output to file and console both

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my project i intend to have multiple log files and hence i am using the categories. But somehow i am getting output to console as well. I have tried many options but no success.
I want to stop output to console. File output should not be affected.

Here is the configuration.

```
#********************Common Configuration**********************
LOG_PATH=./logs
LOG_LEVEL_COMMON=DEBUG

#********************Logging Configuration**********************


#Configure logging level for ENGINE_CLIENT
log4j.category.ENGINE_CLIENT_LOG=${LOG_LEVEL_COMMON},ENGINE_CLIENT
log4j.appender.ENGINE_CLIENT=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.ENGINE_CLIENT.File=${LOG_PATH}/EngineClient.log
log4j.appender.ENGINE_CLIENT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ENGINE_CLIENT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %C{8} [%t] - %m%n
```

Here is Java code ...

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ENGINE_CLIENT");
PropertyConfigurator.configure("./config/default.properties");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copy pasted your code on my local machine incl. your `log4j.properties` but I can't seems to reproduce the issue. It's only logging to the file but not the console.

Just a chance, but have you try to set the `additivity` of your category  inside your `log4j.properties`. Something like this:

```
 log4j.additivity.ENGINE_CLIENT_LOG=false
```

More info here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Appenders_and_Layouts

Comment: Its strange that it works on your system and yes, after adding the line in my config file it works fine. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your root logger by using: `log4j.rootLogger=${LOG_LEVEL_COMMON}, ENGINE_CLIENT`

Comment: This will set my logger to output only one log file. Hence, it defeats the purpose of multiple logging files.